# Prevent Windows 8 from logging out every time I plug/unplug my HDMI cable?

Tags: windows-8, hdmi, login

Every time I plug in my HDMI cable or unplug it, Windows 8 logs me out and I have to log back in and restart all my applications. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: This shouldn't happen at all.  Sounds like a configuration problem  This PC on a Domain by chance?

Comment: @Ramhound, No, it's not on a domain.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix this by following the instructions here: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3519/t/19622776

Basically uninstall and reinstall your display adapter.